# How to do Dependency Injection after application has started in .Net 7

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I am trying to load DLL as plugin in my application, for which I want to Register DI for the new classes,
How I can achieve it during the time when application is in running state.

```
Main Application:-

Interface P1
{
void RegisterDI(IServiceCollection builder);
}

Plugin:-
Public Class World1: P1
{
public void RegisterDI ( IServiceCollection builder)
{
builder.AddScoped<IMyWorld, MyWorld>();
}
```

For now I am storing DLL in file location and loading DLL them and calling the RegisterDI () of World1 class before **builder . Build ()**, But it require restarting of entire application.

It is working fine, but I want to know if there is any possibility by which I can register the DI dynamically in my running application, without the need of restarting it.